# How to Automate Iframe Text flied Using Robotframework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Here it is

[image]

HTML Code

```html
<iframe id="sq-card-number" name="sq-card-number" class="sq-input" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="18" src="https://pci-connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber&amp;app_id=sandbox-sq0idp-tVvPe-svMrqgtzNNRvmStg" allowpaymentrequest="true"></iframe>
```

Below Thing is Script,And Get fails for Input Text Keyword

*** TestCases ***

```
Select Frame    xpath=//iframe[contains(@id,'sq-card-number')]

Input Text  id=sq-card-number   Iframe
```

Comment: You haven't shown the data that's in the iframe. Does it have an input element with the id `sq-card-number`?

Comment: Yes,the Id is 'sq-card-number' for the Text Field

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to appear before trying to type into it?

Comment: Thanks For Response @Bryan Oakley, Ya I tried that Case Also...But its get fails for 'Wait Until Element Is Visible' Keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not differ two different element IDs - you need to select the iframe content first (Select Frame) and then you have to wait for your textbox to appear within the iframe - and wait for this. Unfortunately this is not stated above so: find your text input ID and make sure you replace it in the code example below.

```
    Wait Until Page Contains    id=sq-card-number
    Select Frame    id=sq-card-number
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    id=myTextFieldElement
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=myTextFieldElement
    Input Text    id=myTextFieldElement   Iframe
```

Comment: Thank For Responce @Lubos Jerabek,Yes its  working now..once again Thank.

Comment: @DurgaMaheshK Would you mind marking my answer as correct then please? :) Thank you and no worries!